# cocos2d view as a part of a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have to create an animated progress bar (like a tree growing based on progress). I have done such thing using COOCOS2D. But I now want to make tat cocos2d scene as part of a UIView.. ( To be clear on a page view process is done by some UIKit elements and the progress indication should be of cocos2d scene that i have created.)

Can anyone help me to place the cocos2d scene as part of the UIView?

I got that we have to use EAGLView but have a lot of confusions with adding cococ2d package classes to the project. Can u explain in detail.. or any tutorial link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView` as a subview to your main `UIView`:

```
 [view addSubview:[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView];
```

In your app delegate be sure to set the bounds correctly otherwise the view will cover the whole screen:

```
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:myRect ... ];
```

Comment: Note: if the project is created using cocos2d template, then willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: implementation in RootController from template will not work for not-fullscreen GL view.